# Different VimResized autocmds for Shrinking and Growing

Tags: vim, autocmd

`autocmd VimResized * <foo>` will run the command `<foo>` whenever the vim application's window is resized.
Is there a way to run different commands depending on whether the resize is a shrink or a grow?
And, if so, are there any caveats for console vim?

Comment: Console Vim will never trigger/receive that event.

Comment: @romainl I've already been triggering that event in console vim.

Answer (score 0):

A window is 2-dimensionnal, so the concept of shrinking or growing is quite imprecise : are you talking about the height, or about the width, or about the area?

Let's assume you're talking about the area.

A simple way to do it is to save the last size of the window, on startup and on each time the win is resized; then you just have to compare the last size and the new one, each time the win is resized:

```
" Defines a command to save the current dims:
command! SaveVimDims let g:last_lines=&lines | let g:last_columns=&columns

" Saves the dims on startup:
au VimEnter * SaveVimDims

" Calls the func below, each the win is resized:
au VimResized * call VimResized_Func()

function! VimResized_Func()
    " Gets the area of the last dims:
    let last_area = g:last_lines * g:last_columns

    " Saves the new dims:
    SaveVimDims

    " Gets the area of the new dims:
    let cur_area = g:last_lines * g:last_columns

    " Compares the areas:
    if cur_area < last_area
        " do something when shrinking
    else
        " do something when growing
    endif
endf
```

**This was only tested with Gvim**; I never use Vim in console. Hope it'll work as well